# Bash string substitution adds a preceding space

Tags: bash, sequence, substitution

Why `echo -e {1..3}"\n"` adds a preceding space.

```
1
 2
 3
```

I managed to print the desired output with `echo -en "\r"{1..3}"\n"`

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `{1..3}"\n"` expands to `1\n 2\n 3\n`, and `echo` prints spaces between its arguments.

Use `printf` instead.

```
$ printf '%s\n' {1..3}
1
2
3
```